# How can I use the concat() function on multiple children within an XPath expression

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

something like this works fine "concat('a', 'b')" but i can't it to work as part of an existing expression, i.e.

```
<div class='xyz'>
    <strong>the</strong>
    <sub> one</sub>
</div>

//div[class='xyz']/concat(/strong/text(), /sub/text())
```

i'd like it to return 'the one'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i'd like it to return 'the one'

In **XPath 1.0**, you'd have to do:

```
concat(div[@class='xyz']/strong, div[@class='xyz']/sub)
```

In **XSLT 1.0**, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="div[@class='xyz']/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @jayshilling Why is this an issue? Or rather, why must the concat() function be used to solve this problem? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: is there a different xpath 1.0 way of achieving the same result?  concat would have been the cleanest solution.

Comment: In XPath 1.0 alone, probably not. But XPath is rarely used alone. You also tagged this question as `XSLT` - and in XSLT there must be 50 ways to get the same result without repeating the `div[@class='xyz']` subpath. I only showed one of these.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is XPath 2.0? Otherwise, `concat()` cannot appear on the rh-side of the `/` (or either side of `|`) in an expression, because it returns an atomic value, not a node. This limitation was removed in XPath 2.0 and up.

## XPath 2.0

Your expression is almost correct, the difference being the root node. You started your concat-expressions with `/strong` and `/sub`, but these elements are not rooted at the document root. The rh-side of the expression *takes the focus of the lh-side of the expression*, that is, its focus is on `div`:

```
//div[@class='xyz']/concat(strong/text(), sub/text())
```

In addition (thanks to Rubens), you want the attribute `class`, not the child element `class`.

If your elements do not contain mixed content and you are interested on all text data inside it, you can simplify as follows:

```
//div[@class='xyz']/concat(strong, sub)
```

## XPath 1.0

If you are stuck with XPath 1.0, you can do the following, but it is not (quite) the same:

```
concat(//div[@class='xyz']/strong, //div[@class='xyz']/sub)
```

If you want to apply this to all divs (as indicated by `//`) you should resort to XSLT instead.

Comment: `concat(//div[@class='xyz']/*[self::strong | self::sub])` No, you cannot do that in XPath 1.0 (nor 2.0). Function concat() must have at least 2 arguments.

Comment: @michael.hor257k oh darn, of course! Tx. Confused with string-join, again ;). Answer edited.

Comment: When you say rh-side of an expression, do you mean the rh-side of a `/`?

Comment: @LarsH, yes (or rh- and lh-side of `|`). I've updated my answer for more clarity.